# What is $\int x^4 \, d\mu_p$ on the circle $\{ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ respect to Haar measure on $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fourier-analysis, p-adic-number-theory, haar-measure

I am trying to understand integration with respect to Haar measure.  Here are the first two examples I can think of.  Let $X$ be the variety corresponding to the circle:
$$ X = \{ x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0 \}$$
Then we can consider $X$ over any field... $X(\mathbb{R})$ is the Euclidean circle, but also $X(\mathbb{Q})$ is the rational points.  Then we could consider the completions $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.  Is it fair to assume that:
$$ \overline{X(\mathbb{Q})} = X(\mathbb{Q}_p) $$
in the $p$-adic topology?

These points will now carry a lie group action, just the rotational symmetry of the circle $\text{SO}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ which (superficially) looks like it should behave similar to $\text{SO}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

What is the "average" value of $x$ and $x^2$ with respect to these measures.

- I'd expect by symmetry that $\int_X x \, d\mu_p = 0$
- What could $\int_X x^2 \, d\mu_p$ evaluate to?

Here we get an answer that should work for any measure:

$$2 \int_X x^2 \, d\mu_p =  \int_X x^2 \, d\mu_p + \int_X y^2 \, d\mu_p 
= \int_X (x^2 + y^2) \, d\mu_p = \int_X 1 \, d\mu_p = 1$$

but the question of integrating function over Haar measure over the circle remains.  I guess next would be 4th moment?

$$ \int_{X =  \{ x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0 \} } x^4 \, d\mu_p $$

Comment: well if it evaluates to anything it has to be $1/2$

Comment: I don't understand the question. You seem to have answered it yourself ?

Comment: that works for any measure for which $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$ is measure preserving, and this is the case here because it is part of the group

Comment: @Max i reserve the right to improve the question statement.  certainly within the first hour.  my question is about all even moments $x^{2m}$

Comment: Surely your set is not always compact. Does that affect your considerations?

Comment: I’m sorry, all this stuff is really foreign to me, but doesn’t $d\mu_p$ deliver real values? In that case, what is the variable $x$? It looks like a $p$-adic beast to me. If I’m laboring under a laughable misimpression, I’ll delete this comment, tail between my legs.

Comment: @Lubin Sir, I'm very much winging it here.  **1**) can you exhibit a sequence of points on this "circle" over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ that escapes in the limit?  is this why the term is *locally compact*? The circle $X(\mathbb{Q})$ is definitely not comact. I learn it and forget it. **2**) Reading more closely the took says if you define $f : \mathbb{Q}_p \to \mathbb{C}$ you can do some type of Fourier inversion.  I might try to find some rational solution $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ of  $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ and record some number-theoretic property $(a,b)_p$, and take the average of that in the $p$-adic limit

Comment: @cactus314 if $p=1$ mod $4$ then the "circle" is much more like the hyperbola $xy=1$, and this one has the sequence $x=p^{-n}, y=p^n$ that "escapes in the limit"

Comment: @cactus314 Concretely, for $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$ and $n\ge1$, the element  $1-p^{-2n} = (-1)\cdot p^{-2n}\cdot(1-p^{2n})$ has a square root $y_n$ in $\Bbb Q_p$. With $x_n = p^{-n}$, the sequence $(x_n, y_n)_n$ is on the "circle", but unbounded in $\Bbb Q_p\times \Bbb Q_p$.

Comment: Responding to   **2**) in your last comment, then your question will make sense only after you have chosen your $f:\Bbb Q_p\to\Bbb C$. It might be something involving $x^2$, but $x^2$ itself is not such a function.

Comment: Since the Haar measure is translation invariant, a way to break it with a contradiction is for $a \in X$, the integral $\int x^2d\mu = \int (x+a)^2 d \mu = \int x^2 + 2ax + a^2 d\mu = a^2+ \int x^2d\mu$

Answer (score 2):

You’ve asked a question about the noncompactness of your set in some cases. It happens when $\sqrt{-1}\in\Bbb Z_p$, the integers of $\Bbb Q_p$. And this is for $p\equiv1\pmod4$. Let $i\in\Bbb Z_p$ satisfy $i^2+1=0$.

Letting $x=\frac1{p^n}$, we want to solve $x^2+y^2=1$ for $y$:
\begin{align}
y^2&=1-\frac1{p^{2n}}\\
y&=\sqrt{1-\frac1{p^{2n}}}\\
&=i\sqrt{\frac1{p^{2n}-1}}\\
&=\frac i{p^n}\sqrt{1-p^{2n}}\,,
\end{align}
and $1-p^{2n}$ has a square root in $\Bbb Z_p$ by Hensel’s Lemma, so that its $p$-absolute value is $1$, while the absolute value of $i/p^n$ is the (real) number $p^n$, which goes to infinity.

Comment: In a comment that I had not noticed, @TorstenSchoeneberg has given a shorter and clearer treatment of the same issue.

Comment: I posted my comment at the exact same time when you posted this, which is more detailed. (It's funny that we had the same idea and even chose the same notation.)